# Vagrant provision command failing with bad interpret

Tags: php, apache, vagrant, vagrant-windows, vagrant-provision

I am new in vagrant. I am trying to setup my development environment using Vagrant on my Windows pc. But while run following command on my terminal:

```
    vagrant up --provision
```

It's stuck with following error :

```
 /tmp/vagrant-shell: /tmp/populate_db: /usr/bin/php^M: bad interpret
```

Please let me know you feedback why I am getting above error.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file has carriage return encoded by windows which is different in linux world.

Your solutions:

1. run your file through dos2unix script (http://dos2unix.sourceforge.net)
2. most advanced editors on windows (UltraEdit, Notepad++) allows you to save the format of the file specifically for linux (for example UltraEdit has File/convert with option to convert for linux)